# Nativescript iOS UIColor

Tags: nativescript

I want set the NavigationBar/ActionBar Color to Transparent/Clear in Nativescript.

```
import {BasePage} from "../../shared/BasePage";
import frameModule = require("ui/frame");
import {topmost} from "ui/frame";
import {Observable, EventData} from "data/observable";
import {View} from "ui/core/view";

class HomePage extends BasePage{

   mainContentLoaded(args:EventData){
       let view = <View>args.object;

       if(view.ios){
          var controller = frameModule.topmost().ios.controller;
          controller.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor();
       }

       view.bindingContext = new Observable({ myText: 'This is the home page' });
   }
}
   export = new HomePage();
```

But i get this error: "error TS2304: Cannot find name 'UIColor'"

What i doing wrong?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use the NS color module and convert it to iOS color, so that you can use any color that you want. Like this:

```
var colorModule = require("color");
var red = new colorModule.Color("#ff0000");

var controller = frameModule.topmost().ios.controller;
controller.navigationBar.barTintColor = red.ios;
```

Comment: Thanks for help, how can i use clearColor() from iOS for a transparent navigation bar?

Comment: I have never done this before but there is `translucent` property for iOS navigation bar, you can try to set it to true. Another option is to pass the alpha value to the color. As the example above, it will be ARGB value instead of hex value, like : "#00ff0000", depends on how much transparent you want.

Comment: damn i was dying to find out how to set this thing!